# How to obtain the dimensions of an UIView including its shadow

Tags: ios

I need to get the size that a UIView needs to be shown including its shadow.
Is there an easy way to obtain the dimensions of an UIView including its shadow?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the shadow size using `shadowOffset` and `shadowRadius` properties of view's layer.

```
CGSize offset = view.layer.shadowOffset
CGFloat radius = view.layer.shadowRadius
```

Now, having offset and radius, you need to do some simple math to figure out how it adds to the size already defined by view's `bounds`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what is the formula?

Comment: Why don't you try figuring it out? It's not difficult.

Comment: That's my original question. I guess that's the point of stackoverflow.